# macOS App Delegate termination methods not being called

Tags: swift, macos, appdelegate

I need to remove a file when a macOS app closes. As far as I can tell the various termination methods on the `AppDelegate` are never called in my app.

Others have posted about this in the past and the accepted answer was to change the Info.plist item `Application can be killed immediately when user is shutting down or logging out` to 'NO'. This setting is now in the 'Info' tab in Xcode as opposed to being in an Info.plist file, but either way it is set to 'NO' in my case and these methods are still not being called.

How can I ensure that a method is called when the app is closed?

(Xcode 13.4.1)

For example, using the `AppDelegate` below the file that is created in the call to `applicationDidFinishLaunching` should be removed when the app is closed but it seems none of the three termination methods are being called.

```
@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let path: String = "/mypath/"
    let contents = Data()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: path, contents: contents, attributes: [:])
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        let urlPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        try! fileManager.removeItem(at: urlPath)
    }
    
    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        
        let urlPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        try! fileManager.removeItem(at: urlPath)
        
        return true
    }
    
    func applicationShouldTerminate(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplication.TerminateReply {
        let urlPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        try! fileManager.removeItem(at: urlPath)
        
        return .terminateNow
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `applicationDidFinishLaunching` called? How is the app closed? How did you check if the terminate methods are called?

Comment: @Willeke I haven't exported I am just running from Xcode, so 'closing the app' just means stopping the process in Xcode. Yes `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is called and the file is created, but I have to manually delete the file after I stop the process. Have tried setting breakpoints inside the `AppDelegate` termination methods but I guess there may be a different approach needed for troubleshooting problems with code that is supposed to run after the user has triggered an action to stop the process? But also the fact the file is not automatically removed tells me the methods aren't called

Comment: The Stop button in Xcode just kills the app, it doesn't tell the app to quit. Quit the app like a user would.